# Lightttpd Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, rewrite

How can I rewrite www.domain.de/news/news_944836.html to www.domain.de/news_944836.html in Lighttpd? All my Trys didn´t work :(

Answer (score 1):

```
url.rewrite-final = ( 
"^/news/news_944836.html" => "/news_944836.html"
)
```

if you need that single article to get forwarded.

If everything matching /news/news* should get forwarded, then

```
url.rewrite-final = ( 
"^/news/(.*)$" => "/$1"
)
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
url.rewrite-repeat = (
   "^/news/(.*)$" => "$1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmh, now i get an http404.
the old admin used this chain:

url.rewrite-once = (

"rss/rss91.xml" => "/index.php?id=35344",
            "^/(handel/|kanalliste/|typo3|typo3temp/|typo3conf/|img/|css/|uploads/|fileadmin/|t3lib/|robots.txt|clear.gif|apc.php|apc_cache.php).*$" => "$0",
 "^/$" => "index.php",
 "^/index.php\?.*$" => "$0",
 "^typo3$" => "typo3/index_re.php",
 ".\?([^.]+)" => "index.php?$1",
 ".$" => "index.php"
 )
`

and added at the first line:

`"^/news/(.*)$" => "$1",`

any ideas?

Comment: Try commenting the old rewrites for testing. And try `rewrite-repeat` if there are more rules.